# TeamCity Android setup failure

Tags: android-studio, sdk, android-gradle-plugin, teamcity

i setup teamcity for android build.Getting some errors when trying to run.While i already setup for gradle.
[Issues list](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/23334a11ea7115c5ce942b753d437b7a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It says that `Could not reserve enough space for 1572864KB object heap`. So you need to increase gradle heap size. Do the following please:

1: Open `gradle.properties` file in your Android Studio project.

2: Add this line at the end of the file and change 256 m to how many resources you want to give.

`org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=256m -Xmx256m`